# Ubuntu log file increasing continuosly

Tags: log

My system runs for 2-3 days if there's no power line problem. I basically mine cryptocurrency in my system. So only one terminal based miner runs for the whole time. the problem is my log file increases so much that I've to clean it(with a bash file I found on Github) every day. The log files increases up to 4-6 gb after 24 hours or so. What can I do to stop these? I never use the log files to troubleshoot any problems so I don't need them anyways. Tried to find how to disable logging but couldn't find it.[After cleaning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4QBU.png)

[Before cleaning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1fnv.png)

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu server or a client? What version?

Comment: Which logfile exactly? Which application is writing to the logfile?

Answer (score 0):

You can stop this logging, keeping the rsyslog service running.

Edit the file: /etc/rsyslog.conf.

Comment the line:

```
  $IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf.
```

Restart the service by service rsyslog restart or systemctl restart rsyslog.